# How to create an SQL query that checks for duplicates in multiple tables

Tags: sql, teradata

I want to create an SQL query where I check if duplicates exist in several different tables. I do this in Teradata. I want the output to look like the following.

```
|Table A| |Table B| |Table C| |Table D| |Table D|
```

For each of these columns we can get the value `Y` or `N`.

> (Y means that duplicates exist, N means that duplicates does not exist).

How do I create this script
I have managed to write the code for how to check for duplicates in a a table:

```
SELECT  Customer_Id, Year_Month_Id, count(*)
FROM    A
GROUP BY 1,2
HAVING count(*)>1)
```

Comment: Which script language?

Comment: the script lanuage is SQL

Comment: SQL is not a script language... When you say duplicates in multiple tables, do you mean within a table or between tables?

Comment: Ok, then I want to create an SQL query. I mean within a table. So the output detemines whether there are duplicates within the different tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT #2:

```
 SELECT
 *
 FROM

     (SELECT
    CASE WHEN MAX(cnt) >1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS [Table1]
        FROM
        (
        SELECT 
        customer_id,
        year_month_id,
        COUNT (*) AS Cnt
        FROM
        table1
        GROUP BY 1,2
        ) tbl1 
    ) t1
CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT
    CASE WHEN MAX(cnt) >1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS [Table2]
        FROM
        (
        SELECT 
        customer_id,
        year_month_id,
        COUNT (*) AS Cnt
        FROM
        table2
        GROUP BY 1,2
        ) tbl2
    ) t2
```

EDIT:
For finding duplicates within a single table:

```
select
customer_id,
year_month_id,
case when cnt >1 then 'Y' else 'N' end
from
(
select 
customer_id,
year_month_id,
count (*) as Cnt
from
table1
group by 1,2
) t
```

If you're looking for duplicates between two tables, I'd probably use a union all, something like this:

```
 select
    customer_Id,
    year_month_id
    case when count(*) > 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end
    from
    (
    select distinct
    customer_id,
    year_month_id
    from
    table1
    group by 1,2
    UNION ALL
    select distinct
    customer_id,
    year_month_id
    from
    table2 )t 
    group by 1,2
```

Comment: I am not looking for duplicates between two tables. I am looking for duplicates within the tables.

Comment: Np. I am grateful for your help. This runs. However, I only want one row with either Y or N. This value should explain whether there duplicates in the table or not. How can I fix that?

Comment: Even if I only try the first part before the cross join it still doesn't work. I get the errror message: Syntax error. expected something like an 'Except' keyword or a 'Minus' keyword between the word tbl1 and '.'

Comment: This is strange since tbl1 is the last thing I am writing when I remove the cross join. Do you have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Left out closing parens and aliases, try it now.